# How to remove a registry key?

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to delete some registry Key but VS keeps telling me that I can't write in the registry key and I don't understand why :

```
 public void refInstall()  
 {  
     RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders\MyApp");  
     foreach(string subKeyName in regKey.GetValueNames())  
     {  
         bool exist = Directory.Exists(subKeyName);  
         if (!exist)  
         {  
             regKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(subKeyName);  
             Console.WriteLine(subKeyName + ": N'EXISTE PAS");  
             }  
         }  
     }  
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error returned?

Comment: Could you provide the exact error? Secondly are you running Visual Studio as Admin? Try that.

Comment: Exact error : "UnauthorizedAcessPermission : impossible to write in the registryKey" (or something like that, I'm running VS in french ^^)

Comment: The two answers seem to cover everything.  Does it work?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have write access to HKLM. You would need to run with elevated privileges in order for this to succeed.

It's always been the case that rights to HKLM have been restricted to members of the administrators group. The thing that changed was in Vista when UAC was introduced and users habitually started running without admin rights.

It may not be what you want to hear, but you need to get out of the habit of writing to this area of the registry, and find a different way to achieve your goals. The only time it is reasonable for a desktop app to expect write access to HKLM (or indeed Program Files directory) is at install time.

Once you fix your code as described by arx, you'll then have to tackle this issue.

Comment: I'm admin and when I run the .exe in the debug folder "as administrator" it crashes ...

Comment: Admin users don't have write access to HKLM by default. Under UAC they run with a restricted rights token. They have to explicitly elevate the process to get full rights. But the point remains, you have to change your habits.

Answer (score 1):

This has one obvious problem:

You are iterating through registry **values** but trying to delete them as if they were **keys**.

If you want to work with values use `RegistryKey.DeleteValue`.

If you want to work with keys use `RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames`.

Another problem:

You are opening the registry key with read-only access.  You need (note the extra bool on the end):

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders\MyApp", true);
```

(Deleted comments about Directory.Exists acting on the file system.  This is deliberate as darky89 explains below.)

Comment: "Directory.Exists acts on the file system, not the registry." Ouch!!

Comment: MMMmmmm I know what I'm doing, I'm just cleaning the folder that are deleted but are still in the registry :)

Comment: Don't worry about that ^^ But you were right, this was an obvious problem but it is still not working, I still can't write in registry grrrrr :p